# Angular 8 drop down selected option not showing, how come?

Tags: angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, html-select

This question has been asked frequently. My situation is apparently different from all the others as I can't find a solution for it from the existing answers.

I have this code:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="getExceptions(f)" #f="ngForm">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
              <label class="col-form-label" for="aantal">Aantal meldingen per pagina?</label>
              <select name="selectedQuantity" id="aantal" class="form-control" ngModel>
                <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option}}</option>

              </select>
            </div>
.
.
.
</form>
```

options is defined as:

```
private options: string[] = ['10', '20', '50'];
```

I would like to show "10" as the default selected value but whatever I do the drop down keeps showing a blank for the selected value. Clicking the drop down shows the values 10, 20 and 30. So it is filled properly.

What did I try:

```
<option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option" [selected]="option==10">{{option}}
</option>
```

and

```
<option [value]="10" [selected]="true == true">10</option>
<option [value]="20">20</option>
<option [value]="50">50</option>
```

and

```
<option [value]="10" selected>10</option>
<option [value]="20">20</option>
<option [value]="50">50</option>
```

It has something to do with the binding because if I remove the 'ngModel' from the select tag it shows the value I want to use as the default value (10). Sort of. I can't read the selected value anymore but the default value is showing.

I have never done anything with plunkr but will try to get an example working there and then paste a link to that in here.

Comment: Can you please provide Stackblitz for this scenario?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try setting `ngModel` like this:

.ts

```
  private options: string[] = ["10", "20", "50"];
  selectedQuantity = "10";
```

.html

```
<select name="selectedQuantity" id="aantal" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedQuantity">
    <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option" >{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9gejbd?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: angular template meant to be used without create any variable at the component level that why a lot of people still used it but not me  and all form value will bound to the `#f`

Comment: you answer will work but I just want to mention this 

Comment: I had to remove `[(ngModel)]` and replace (ngModelChange) with `(change)` thanks to a warning in Chrome. Both properties were causing an issue that html select was not loading options properly after page load. So, always check warnings to see if there are deprecated angular properties before applying changes.

Comment: @AdritaSharma what if i don't want to set the starting value. Because the problem with me is i want allow users to select. Even if i allow user to select. I want to show that value as disabled.

Answer (score 6):

Since We just want a placeholder for our select tag why not just try a different approach.

Using disabled attribute somehow makes angular ignore it. Which then perfectly works as placeholder.

```html
<select class="form-select" name="NAME" ngModel>
   <option value="" disabled selected>Select text</option>
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
   <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

just assign value to a select

```
 <select [value]="10" ngModel>
 ...
```

Answer (score 3):

use like below

```
<option [value]="10" [selected] ="true">10</option>
```

you have to use select as a property binding.

let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngModel for select with default value in one variable assigned to it as -

```
    <select name="selectedQuantity" id="aantal" 
      class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
      <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
           {{option}}
           </option>
     </select>
```

and value will be is as -
  selectedOption: string = '10';

Answer (score 0):

try like this  `[ngModel]="10"`

```
<select name="selectedQuantity" id="aantal" class="form-control" [ngModel]="10">
   <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option}}</option> 
</select>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jcqlln)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing model binding, just the option like that your model:

```
    export class MyModel
    {
       public field1: number = 0;
    }
```

```xml
    <select [(ngModel)]="myModel.field1">
      <option value="" > your value 1 < /option >
      <option value="">your value 2</option>
    </select>
```

So the trick is that you need to set the default value in your model which is zero set in the field1 in above model and will set the value1 as selected option

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue because there was a difference between the `name` and `[(ngModel)]` values.

Here is the working code:

```
<select id="nodeKpiDataType" name="nodeKpi.dataType" [(ngModel)]="nodeKpi.dataType">
  <option *ngFor="let kpiType of kpyDataTypes" [value]="kpiType">{{ kpiType }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue default selected value was not showing in angular reactive form but after implementing property binding issue was fixed. hope that this will help someone.

```
<option [ngValue]="null" [selected]="true">Select Account Type</option>
```